# ZeroMQ / NetMQ: PushSocket.SendFrame not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, zeromq, netmq

I am trying to send a "fire-and-forget" type message using NetMQ.  I do not care about waiting for a response.  This is for logging, and I care more about performance than being certain my message was received, and I especially don't want my web application to hang if the logging server is down.  This client code is in a web api application, if that matters.

I have the following code on my web api client:

```
using (var client = new PushSocket(">tcp://localhost:9001"))
{
    client.SendFrame("hello!");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

This code works.  But if I ommit the Thread.Sleep, the server never receives the message.  What is the correct way to do this?  I'm assuming it's not Thread.Sleep.

Answer (score 0):

ZeroMQ (and I assume NetMQ) 'send' calls are asynchronous and they return before the message is sent on the underlying network layer.
When the last '}' is reached your socket is destroyed and any messages not yet sent are lost. The sleep stops the socket from being destroyed for long enough to allow the message to be sent.

Ideally you want to construct a single socket somewhere and use it repeatedly which will be faster and avoid the need for the sleep.

Im no c# expert though, so how you would do that is unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

Without the Tread.sleep your socket will be destroyed before it might be sent. Depending on the rest of your application, you could consider keeping the socket alive, by using it as an object specific socket.

```
public class foo
{
     PushSocket client;
     public foo()
     {
         client =  = new PushSocket(">tcp://localhost:9001);
         client.SendFrame("hello!");
     }
}
```

The socket will not be destroyed as long as this foo instance is kept alive. 
This way your message will be received